# access a jquery variable inside typescript

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call a Web api with jquery $ajax() function, after making the call I wont to store the result in my typescript variable but i didn't figure how to do that .

```
 $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'URL',
  data: { email:'test@gmail.com',
      password:'pass'}

})
.done(function(msg ) {

  this.response=msg;

}) .fail(function(msg) {
  this.response=msg;
})
```

Comment: declare a variable outside of the ajax call and store the result there.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors uhm.. no...

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is, and even if it were, doing what you're doing isn't going to work. You need to make use of the promise $.ajax returns instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set it on the object making the Ajax call you can use an arrow function to capture the contextual this

```
class MyCaller {
   response: any;
   doCall() {
      $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: 'URL',
         data: { email:'test@gmail.com', password:'pass'}
     }).done((msg ) => {
       // this refers to MyCaller, with a simple function it would not
       this.response=msg; 
     }).fail((msg) => {
       this.response=msg;
     })     
   }
}
```

As long as you are using TypeScript you could take advantage of async and await to simplify your code. This would be equivalent :

```
class MyCaller {
    response: any;
    async doCall() {
        try {
            this.response = await $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'URL',
                data: { email:'test@gmail.com', password:'pass'}
            })
        }catch(error) {
            this.response = error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to hear :)